# Exponential Inequality

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

I was working on a problem and reduced it to showing the following inequality:

$$2x e^{x^2/6} \ge e^x - e^{-x}  \text{ for $x \ge 0$}$$

I tried expanding everything in Taylor series to no avail. I also tried defining the function $f(x):= 2xe^{x^2/6} - e^x + e^{-x}$, showing $f(0) = 0$ and trying to show $f'(x) \ge 0$ for $x \ge 0$, but I couldn't show the last part.

Is there something easy I'm missing?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is $2xe^{x^2/6}\geq e^x-e^{-x}\Rightarrow (6e^{x^2/6})'\geq(e^x+e^{-x})'$. But I don't know if this could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Taylor series approach works if, for every $k\geqslant0$, $a_k\geqslant b_k$, with
$$
a_k=\frac1{k!6^k},\qquad b_k=\frac1{(2k+1)!}.
$$
Now, $a_0=b_0=1$ and, for every $k\geqslant1$,
$$
\frac{a_k}{b_k}=\frac{2k(2k+1)}{6k}\cdot\frac{a_{k-1}}{b_{k-1}}=\frac{2k+1}3\cdot\frac{a_{k-1}}{b_{k-1}}\geqslant\frac{a_{k-1}}{b_{k-1}},
$$
hence the result holds.

Comment: Ha, I came to that same conclusion but when I looked at it, I somehow thought $a_1 = 1/6 < b_1 = 1/(2+1)!$ ... Thank you!

Comment: Since $a_0=b_0$, if $a_1\lt b_1$ were true, the inequality would not hold for small enough positive values of $x$... :-) Nice question, by the way.